# Does init_on_free immediately zero VMAs that are unmapped?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, memory

This feature, added in commit [6471384a](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=6471384af2a6530696fc0203bafe4de41a23c9ef), is supposed to initialize pages when they are freed. This is done by in the source file [`mm/page_alloc.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.11/source/mm/page_alloc.c) by `free_pages_prepare()` and `prep_new_page()`.

When a VMA is unmapped (either manually or automatically upon process termination), is all the process memory guaranteed to be initialized to zero? What about kernel slabs pertaining to actions such as sending data over a pipe or passing pages between kernel and user? Note an important exception described in the commit message which applies to a few slabs (but never user pages):

> Both init_on_alloc=1 and init_on_free=1 guarantee that the allocator returns zeroed memory.  The two exceptions are slab caches with constructors and SLAB_TYPESAFE_BY_RCU flag.  Those are never zero-initialized to preserve their semantics.

Consider the following hypothetical script which lists all device-mapper crypt keys that are smaller than 256 bits and then removes all device-mapper targets, deleting the keys in the process:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0
dmsetup table --showkeys | while IFS= read table; do
    set -- $table # key material is now present in $6
    [[ ${#6} -lt 64 ]] && ((count++))
done
echo "$count keys less than 256 bits"
dmsetup remove_all --force
```

Will any key data remain after all involved processes have terminated when `init_on_free=1`? Assume no swapping or tracing, slub debugging and page poisoning are disabled, etc.

---

Interestingly, `dmsetup` does not use [`DM_SECURE_DATA_FLAG`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=lvm2.git;a=blob;f=libdm/misc/dm-ioctl.h;h=cdb38f639a46cc99cc5e2178912d730be900ca5e#l357), a flag in the buffer passed to DM via an ioctl which enables wiping of the buffer in [`drivers/md/dm-ioctl.c:1855`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/drivers/md/dm-ioctl.c#L1855):

```
secure_data = param_kernel->flags & DM_SECURE_DATA_FLAG;

[...]

/* Wipe the user buffer so we do not return it to userspace */
if (secure_data && clear_user(user, param_kernel->data_size))
    goto bad;
```

Presumably this won't matter when the process terminates and all its pages are freed.